# EBS - Volumes Usage is higher than what i actually see

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon Free Tier account

[image: Services by Usage]

It's showing that i am using 25.75 GB,

I only have a single EC2 instance running, what is this "EBS - Volume"

I have a 30GB disc attached to this instance and as you an see below it's showing only 10% used,

Where is this 25.75GB coming from?

[image: aws-disk]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are charged for the EBS volume you provision, not storage used.

When you provision an EBS volume all of that space is reserved for you. You create a volume, your operating system formats it and has exclusive use of it, and probably zeros out most of the space. It's solely allocated to you, so you pay for it.

This is different from S3 and EFS, where you pay for only what you use. The [AWS free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) gives you 30GB free, so you shoudln't be charged. You may be charged for snapshots of the volume though.